Remove the indentation for one line or paragraph within enumeration environment
See the blue box in the screenshot. I have a paragraph INSIDE an enumeration. I want to remove the indentation for that so that the paragraph will be aligned to the left WITHOUT indentation.

Below is my working code:
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\linespread{1.1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{caption}
\title{\textbf{CHECKLISTS}}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    This is a paragraph before the enumeration. This is a paragraph before the enumeration. This is a paragraph before the enumeration. This is a paragraph before the enumeration. This is a paragraph before the enumeration. \par
    \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item First line. First line. First line. First line. First line. First line. First line. First line. 
        \item Second line. Second line. Second line. Second line. Second line. Second line. Second line. 
        \item Third line. Third line. Third line. Third line. Third line. Third line. Third line. Third line. Third line. 
        
        This is a paragraph \textbf{WITHIN the enumeration}. This is a paragraph \textbf{WITHIN the enumeration}. This is a paragraph \textbf{WITHIN the enumeration}. This is a paragraph \textbf{WITHIN the enumeration}.
        

        \item Fourth line. Fourth line. Fourth line. Fourth line. Fourth line. Fourth line. Fourth line. 
    \end{enumerate}

    The enumeration has ended here.\par
    \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

    This is a new story. This is a new story. This is a new story. This is a new story. This is a new story. This is a new story. This is a new story. This is a new story. 
\end{document}


Just out idle curiosity: Why are the contents of almost all cells encased in \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{...} or \multicolumn{1}{l|}{...} wrappers?

Incidentally, your code generates severely overfull lines as the left-hand tabular environment is wider than 0.5\linewidth. If you were to change the widths of the minipage environments to 0.65\linewidth and 0.35\linewidth, there would be much less of an apparent difference between the table layouts inside and outside the enumerate environment.

I would like to reframe my question. All I want is to remove the indentation WITHIN the enumeration for a paragraph.

Why changing the question to a completely different one? The new question is duplicate.

As I see it, the visual/aesthetic problem is caused by the left-hand table being quite a bit wider than 0.5\linewidth. Once you assign more appropriate relative widths to the minipage environments -- say, 0.65\linewidth and 0.35\linewidth -- the difference between the table layouts inside and outside the enumerate environment is much less apparent.
At any rate, unless your tables are severely space-constrained (which isn't the case here), I would not mess with the layout of the enumerate environment.
Separately, do please simplify your tables by getting rid of the multitude of \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{...} and \multicolumn{1}{l|}{...} wrappers and by getting rid of the "outer" tabular environment. Giving the table a more open "look" -- by using fewer but well-spaced horizontal rules  may also be a good idea. See the following screenshot and code for some specific coding suggestions.

\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\linespread{1.1}
\usepackage{setspace} \setstretch{1.1}
\usepackage{parskip} % zero \parindent, non-zero \parskip

\usepackage{enumerate} % I'd use 'enumitem' package
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{textfont=bf}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First line. First line. First line. First line. First line. First line. First line. First line. 
\item Second line. Second line. Second line. Second line. Second line. Second line. Second line. 
\item Third line. Third line. Third line. Third line. Third line. Third line. Third line. Third line.

% Table 1       
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\linewidth}
\captionof{table}{Major Losses from 2020 to 2023}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}llr@{}}
\toprule
    Year & Bets & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Loss} \\
\midrule
    2020 & AMZN, AAPL, GOOG, META  & \$12,067 \\ 
    2021 & PFE, T                  & \$10,559 \\ 
    2022 & LULU                    & \$10,565 \\ 
    2023 & BABA, C, WFC            & \$14,390 \\ 
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
& \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Total}} & \textbf{\$42,581}                       
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
%
% Table 2           
\begin{minipage}[t]{.35\linewidth}
\captionof{table}{Largest Losses}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}lr@{}}
    \toprule
    Company & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Loss} \\ 
    \midrule
    BABA    & \$11,410 \\ 
    X       & \$11,854 \\ 
    D       & \$11,879 \\ 
    MU      & \$12,565 \\ 
    OUST    & \$8,752  \\ 
    MSFT    & \$3,804  \\ 
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Total}} & \textbf{\$60,264}        
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\item Fourth line. Fourth line. Fourth line. Fourth line. Fourth line. Fourth line. Fourth line. 

\end{enumerate}

The enumeration ends here.

\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}

This is a new story. This is a new story. This is a new story. This is a new story. 
This is a new story. This is a new story. This is a new story. This is a new story. 

\begin{center}
% Table 3       
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\linewidth}
\captionof{table}{Major Losses from 2020 to 2023}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}llr@{}}
\toprule
    Year & Bets & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Loss}    \\
\midrule
    2020 & AMZN, AAPL, GOOG, META  & \$12,067 \\ 
    2021 & PFE, T                  & \$10,559 \\ 
    2022 & LULU                    & \$10,565 \\ 
    2023 & BABA, C, WFC            & \$14,390 \\ 
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
& \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Total}} & \textbf{\$42,581}                       
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
%
% Table 4           
\begin{minipage}[t]{.35\linewidth}
\captionof{table}{Largest Losses}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}lr@{}}
    \toprule
    Company & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Loss} \\ 
    \midrule
    BABA    & \$11,410 \\ 
    X       & \$11,854 \\ 
    D       & \$11,879 \\ 
    MU      & \$12,565 \\ 
    OUST    & \$8,752  \\ 
    MSFT    & \$3,804  \\ 
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Total}} & \textbf{\$60,264}        
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{center}

\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}

\end{document}


Addendum to address the OP's revised question, viz.,

All I want is to remove the indentation WITHIN the enumeration for a paragraph.

For that, it suffices to (a) be sure the enumitem package is loaded -- as is the case in the revised query posted by the OP, (b) insert
\end{enumerate}

right before
This is a paragraph \textbf{WITHIN the enumeration}. 
This is a paragraph \textbf{WITHIN the enumeration}. 
This is a paragraph \textbf{WITHIN the enumeration}. 
This is a paragraph \textbf{WITHIN the enumeration}.

and (c) insert
\begin{enumerate}[resume]

immediately after that paragraph, but also before the next \item directive.

Thanks a lot for your time. Can you check my revised question? Thank you!

@fhk - Please see the addendum I just posted.

That solved the problem. Your answer produced the outcome I desired. Thank you so much!

Idea stolen from exam class.
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\linespread{1.1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fullwidth}[1]{% #1 = text
  \par\hspace*{-\@totalleftmargin}\parbox{\textwidth}{\strut #1\strut}\par}
\makeatother

\title{\textbf{CHECKLISTS}}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    This is a paragraph before the enumeration. This is a paragraph before the enumeration. This is a paragraph before the enumeration. This is a paragraph before the enumeration. This is a paragraph before the enumeration. \par
    \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item First line. First line. First line. First line. First line. First line. First line. First line. 
        \item Second line. Second line. Second line. Second line. Second line. Second line. Second line. 
        \item Third line. Third line. Third line. Third line. Third line. Third line. Third line. Third line. Third line. 
        
\fullwidth{This is a paragraph \textbf{WITHIN the enumeration}. This is a paragraph \textbf{WITHIN the enumeration}. This is a paragraph \textbf{WITHIN the enumeration}. This is a paragraph \textbf{WITHIN the enumeration}.}
        

        \item Fourth line. Fourth line. Fourth line. Fourth line. Fourth line. Fourth line. Fourth line. 
    \end{enumerate}

    The enumeration has ended here.\par
    \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

    This is a new story. This is a new story. This is a new story. This is a new story. This is a new story. This is a new story. This is a new story. This is a new story. 
\end{document}

